# Using php variables and css to change the background color based on events and sql data

Tags: php, html, sql, css

Hope this makes sense, I'll hopefully paint a clear picture.

```
<?php $rx_event_color = $rx_image_color = '#FF0000';
if ($a['rx_event_exists'] == 1) { $rx_event_color = '#00FF00'; }

if ($a['rx_scanned'] == 1) { $rx_image_color = '#00FF00'; }
else if ($a['rx_scanned'] > 1) { $rx_image_color = '#FFFF00'; }
?>
```

I don't want the whole background td to change color, only the text inside the td based on the event (data in sql)

```
if ($a['rx_event_exists'] == 0)
    {
    echo "<tr><td style='background:$rx_event_color'><a href='" 
                    . matry::here_to('new', array('tfilt'=>'WR', 'pfilt'=>$patient->code))
                    . "'>**Rx Event Not Created**</a></td></tr>";
    }
```

I tried to just change background to color and also tried adding it in a div instead... i figured it should be easier than it's turning out to be.. that's why i'm asking here. Thanks in advance my friends.

Comment: Then why are you using background: in style, use color: instead.

Comment: instead of dynamically creating the css and injecting it inline (making your code smell)... create a class of each colour in your main css and then just add the class name based on the value you have in the db

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for responding, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the style attribute to the anchor tag, as the link's styling is controlling the coloring of the text, not the `td`.  Color and background-color can be used interchangeably here, depending on your purposes.

```
<td><a href='...' style='color:$rx_event_color'>...</a></td>
```

Alternately, you could use classes:

```
.notfound a { color: red }

<td class="notfound"><a href="...">...</a></td>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I forgot I could attach styles to the link. I completely forgot. Thanks. This worked.